# trigger to send email when new object is created in DB

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to create a trigger that sends me an email whenever a new object is created in a database. Can someone point me in the right direction? I assume this is relatively easy?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on DML triggers

Comment: For a new object, you actually want a [DDL trigger](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/). However, I would log to a queue table, and have a background job poll it frequently enough for changes, rather than make the creation of the object wait for the e-mail to be sent.